# Automatic image uploading in php issue

Tags: javascript, php

SAy, i have script for uploading image to servor and display.It is also working fine.But, i want not to upload image manually to form,just double click the image and it will be uploaded in a same way as we have option in google "search chrome for this image" or just a button using jquery when clicked image will be uploaded.Any idea,my code i use to upload files:

```
<?php
$target_path = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
echo "<img src='".$target_path."' class='healthfood' />";
}
?>      

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="upload file" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="file" value="upload file" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input id="file" name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
         <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
// brefore this don't froget to add Jquery Libary and if alredy exist don't repeat 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#file").on("change",function(){
       // alert("a");
        $(this).parent("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Use [jQuery.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), The `.parents()` and `.parent()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. Also, `$( "html" ).parent()` method returns a set containing document whereas `$( "html" ).parents()` returns an empty set.

Comment: @Ranidubey to accept an answer, just click the sign "checked" next to it.

Answer (score -2):

Even simpler:

```html
<form id=form1 action=whatever>
  <input type=file id=x /><br/>
  <input type=button onclick='form1.submit();' value='Click This to Upload'/>
</form>
```